How do I make jni run a C program?
I have a program in jni (java native interface), which should display the text "hello world" in C
#include "MyJavaClass.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Função nativa chamada pelo Java
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJavaClass_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject){
    printf("hello world");
  }

java calls this function to display the message in the console
public class MyJavaClass {

    public native void sayHello();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("sum");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyJavaClass().sayHello();
    }
}

compiling
gcc -c -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\include\win32" main.c -o main.o

gcc -shared -o sum.dll main.o --% -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias

and running
java -cp .  -D"java.library.path"=. MyJavaClass

the console displays exactly this:

I followed all the patterns in this video (some parts of the compilation I had to edit to work) however I didn't get the same result as this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/-_JiA7ldmvg?si=NHg3c3A5IvzZlKIy

Add a JNI_OnLoad to your DLL with a print statement. Does it print anything?
